# Sum having a condition

Tags: sql

I've a table that has this information:

[image]

And need to get the following information:

- If the country of the same person name (in this case Artur) is different, then I need to sum the two values of quantity from the max date (in this case 04/10) and return both person (Artur) and the qty (15k)
- If the country of the same person name (in this case Joseph) is the same, then I need only the first row of the max date available.

I'm really struguling as I'm not sure how to implement the logic into my code:

```
Select
table.person,
table.quantity
From
(
Select
table.date,
table.person,
table.country,
table.quantity,
ROW_NUMBER () over (
PARTITION by table.code, table.person
ORDER by table.date DESC
) AS rn
FROM
table
WHERE table.date >= DATE '{2020-04-10}' -5
) a
WHERE a.RN IN (1,2)
```

Is it possible to create a rule to sum rows 1 and 2 when country is different (Artur case) and only return row number 1 when the country is the same for a name (Joseph case)?

Comment: In future questions please provide the data as reusable text, `not` as an image. Table DDL and inserts are even better.

Answer (score 3):

Use `dense_rank()` or `max()` as a window function:

```
select person, sum(quantity)
from (select t.*,
             max(date) over (partition by person) as max_date
      from t
     ) t
where date = max_date
group by person;
```

EDIT:

Hmmm . . . I think you might want one row per country per person on the max date.  If so:

```
select person, sum(quantity)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by person, country order by date desc) as seqnum_pc,
             rank() over (partition by person order by date desc) as seqnum_p
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum_p = 1 and seqnum_pc = 1
group by person;
```

Comment: Actually, I just want to SUM two rows of the same person if the country is different, and if the country is the same for the same person, just return the max quantity of that person on that country. EDIT: I don't need to return the date or the country, just the SUM if countries are different and the first row of that person if the country is the same.

Comment: the second query shown above return `Artur, 15000` and `Joseph, 8000' which is what I believe you asked for, see this working example  https://dbfiddle.uk/markdown?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ecbf26152b44769da2601988a2375d21 and in future please include sample data in a form we can use (not images).